# Node.js socket timeout not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timeout, keep-alive

I've been using Node.js's [setTimoeut](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) on a socket, and I don't think it's really doing what I want it to do. I want it to be able to timeout a socket when there is *no response* from the server. So if the server doesn't send me data or accept any data sent from my end, I want it to close the socket.

Currently, I have the clients sending a "NoOp" command to keep the socket open. When the server *does not* receive a NoOp command, the socket is closed as expected. However, the client who keeps queueing NoOp commands never gets a socket timeout event. I'm guessing that trying to send data counts as socket activity whether or not the server accepts it. But if the server also hasn't accepted it for a while, I would like that to count as a timeout as well.

How can I make a timer based on whether or not the data is being received?

My current socket creation code that doesn't do what I really want.

```
// Our timeout
socket.setTimeout( 60000 );

// Set his callbacks
socket
.on( 'data', this.dataReceived.bind( this ) )
.on( 'close', this.socketClosed.bind( this ) )
.on( 'error', this.socketError.bind( this ) )
.on( 'end', this.socketEnd.bind( this ) )
.on( 'timeout', this.socketTimeout.bind( this ) )
.on( 'drain', this.socketBufferDrain.bind( this ) );
```

Comment: start a timeout, clear+reset it every time you receive data?

Comment: That would work if the server sends data. That could be an option for the server to also send noop commands to the clients. I was hoping for a "cleaner" way.